# Can we run a current Jenkins with older slaves?

Tags: java, jenkins

We've been using Jenkins to run our builds and (some) of our deploys, for some time. We're planning the move from SVN to Git for our VC.

The current Git plugin for Jenkins requires Jenkins 1.625. We're running 1.612.

1.625 requires Java 7. I've noticed that more current releases require Java 8, and support Java 11.

Our problem is that we have some projects that still build (God help us) on Windows XP, so we have a Jenkins slave running on an XP build machine.

And, of course, Windows XP doesn't support Java 8.

So, can a current version of Jenkins control an older version of the Jenkins slave? Could we install Jenkins 2.164+ on the master, leave the slave on the XP machine running the Jenkins 1.612 slave, and have them successfully talk to each other?

Comment: Goingnto suggest you review the " Windows Slave Installer Service" and decide for yourself, but would suggest the answer is likely no. https://github.com/jenkinsci/windows-slave-installer-module/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you cannot run a master against an older slave.

We haven't entirely decided what to do, but it looks like we're probably going to configure a new build machine with a current Jenkins install, and leave the old machines alone until we finally get rid of the old XP projects